# CSS removed for a while during page postback ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have faced a very strange issue in my application, at some places while a postback event occurs and page reload for a sec or two css will removed and html structure loads only then suddenly css applies.

This is random issue, it is not very long when css not appears but yes it is visible and affecting UI and customers experience. Please see below what happens for 1-2 secs (page without css) -

[image]

I am using ASP.NET web forms - 4.5, MSSQL Server as database, js and default Ajax controls provided in VS 2012.

Can anyone please share how to come out of this issue or any fixes to that.

I am preparing applications from last 5 years but this is first time I faced such kind of issue, please help, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: where did you put or call your `CSS`?

Comment: Seems like the css is being reloaded each time the page is viewed. How do you load the css on client side?

Comment: Css files are called on head in Main.Master page.

Answer (score -1):

convert your

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

into

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

You got solution

Comment: convert your <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
into
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

You got solution